# Playwright get long polling response body

Tags: puppeteer, long-polling, playwright

How can you get the response body "stream" of a long polling response in Microsoft Playwright or Puppeteer using `page.on('response',myfunction)`?
The content type of the response is  `'text/event-stream'`.
The code stops at `await response.body()`, is there some solution in Python? 
I would be grateful for solutions in other languages as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked this on the Playwright Github:
This is the anwser of someone responsible for the project (I hope it's alright if I post this here):
**"For now subscribing to EventSource.onmessage via javascript is your best bet if you can't wait until the request is finished."** 
He changed my question into a feature request.

Comment: Linking https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/7466 to it for further reference.

Comment: Wasn't sure if it was necesarry, I always get told that I should not post links on stackoverflow